# Tab View with List throws error UITableView was told to layout its visible cells and other contents without being in the view hierarchy

Tags: swift, uitableview, swiftui

## Overview:

I have a SwiftUI project which shows ContentView

ContentView shows a Tab view with 2 Tabs:

1. Text
2. OrderListView (Uses a list)

### Steps to reproduce:

When the following is done an Warning is thrown in the console:

1. Tap on 2nd Tab
2. Tap on 1st Tab
3. Notice the warning in the console:

### Warning:

```
Warning once only: UITableView was told to layout its visible cells and other contents
without being in the view hierarchy (the table view or one of its superviews has not been
added to a window). This may cause bugs by forcing views inside the table view to load and
perform layout without accurate information (e.g. table view bounds, trait collection,
layout margins, safe area insets, etc), and will also cause unnecessary performance
overhead due to extra layout passes. Make a symbolic breakpoint at 
UITableViewAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy to catch this in the debugger and see what
caused this to occur, so you can avoid this action altogether if possible, or defer it
until the table view has been added to a window. Table view: 

<_TtC7SwiftUIP33_BFB370BA5F1BADDC9D83021565761A4925UpdateCoalescingTableView:
0x7fddc985ae00; baseClass = UITableView; frame = (0 0; 414 852); clipsToBounds = YES;
autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600003053120>; layer = <CALayer: 
0x600003e784c0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {414, 0}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 
0, 83, 0}; dataSource: (null)>
```

## Code:

### ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Text("aaa")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "1.square.fill")
                    Text("1st tab")
                }
            OrderListView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "2.square.fill")
                    Text("2nd tab")
                }
        }
        .font(.headline)    }
}
```

### OrderListView.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

struct OrderListView : View {

    var orders = [Order]()

    var body: some View {

        List(orders) { order in

            Text("bbb")
                .font(.body)
        }
    }
}
```

### Order.swift

```
import Foundation

class Order : Identifiable {

    let id : Int

    init(id: Int) {

        self.id = id
    }
}
```

Comment: Got same issue when dismissing a view from a NavigationView inside a Tab view

Comment: Same issue when pushing a view then going back. Didn't find a solution yet.

Comment: I think it would be good to file a bug, I have filed a bug. (via Feedback Assistant app)